# how to use React Hook for componentWillReceiveProps

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i'm trying to change the class based component to react hooks. where you can compare the previous and upcoming props and find the difference to mutate the state.

**class_component**

```
componentWillReceiveProps(props) {
    if (
      props.artistState.nextVideos.length >
      this.props.artistState.nextVideos.length
    ) {
      const diff =
        props.artistState.nextVideos.length -
        this.props.artistState.nextVideos.length
      this.setState(state => {
        return { loadingItems: state.loadingItems - diff }
      })
    }
}
```

**hooks**

```
function usePrevious(value) {
  // The ref object is a generic container whose current property is mutable ...
  // ... and can hold any value, similar to an instance property on a class
  const ref = useRef();

  // Store current value in ref
  useEffect(() => {
    ref.current = value;
  }, [value]); // Only re-run if value changes

  // Return previous value (happens before update in useEffect above)
  return ref.current;
}


const prevVideosLen = usePrevious(artistState.nextVideos.length);

useEffect(() => {
  if (prevVideosLen) {
    console.log('artist:: Card', {
      length1: artistState.nextVideos.length,
      length2: prevVideosLen,
    });
    if (artistState.nextVideos.length > prevVideosLen) {
      const diff = artistState.nextVideos.length - prevVideosLen;
      console.log('artist:: Card', { diff });
      setLoadingItems((prev) => prev - diff);
    }
  }
}, [artistState, prevVideosLen]);
```

i tried with using with previous but i'm getting the prev state same as the current one? and how do i achieve the same functionality of componentWillReceiveProps on the hooks.

Comment: The recipe for [`usePrevious`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-faq.html#how-to-get-the-previous-props-or-state) doesn't use a dependency array as you want the effect to trigger every render. Not sure if that is cause for issue, but you may as well follow the recipe correctly, right? ‍♂️

Comment: @DrewReese i tried adding the array length to usePrevious hook, but still no result, any idea for using the recipe correctly?

Answer (score 0):

use can React Hook for componentWillReceiveProps like this

```
useEffect( () => {
        console.log('posts updated');
},
[props.posts])
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: @Kavesh useEffect will change according to the newer props but what i'm trying to get the difference with previous props and incoming props. but unable to achieve. sometimes using useEffect for every lifecycle method still confuses me to use it properly